# Bigcommerce Add To Cart Pop-Up

Tags: bigcommerce

When using bigcommerce before, we were able to choose whether or not to have a pop up or take the user to the cart whenever they clicked the "Add to Cart" button. Does anybody know if this feature has been taken out by BigCommerce or where I can find that setting now? Thank you!

Comment: Are you using stencil or blueprint?

Comment: @Alyss I'm using Stencil

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you know if you're using the Stencil or Blueprint framework?

If you're using blueprint, you can go to "Store Setup > Store Settings > Display" and choose "Take Them to Their Shopping Cart".

If you're using stencil, that feature is hidden and you have to do customization for it to work. If your products don't have any options, you can follow the instructions on this page: https://support.bigcommerce.com/articles/Public/How-can-I-add-a-product-to-the-cart-with-a-link/#add-to-cart.

However, if you have options, this won't work because it doesn't updated the sku in the url. What i did to get this to work was to edit the `product-details.js`

First you need to download the theme in order to edit the js file. Then, starting on `line 234`, you'll see the following code:

```
// Open preview modal and update content
if (this.previewModal) {
    this.previewModal.open();
    this.updateCartContent(this.previewModal, response.data.cart_item.hash);
} else {
    this.$overlay.show();
    // if no modal, redirect to the cart page
    this.redirectTo(response.data.cart_item.cart_url || this.context.urls.cart);
}
```

Directly under the comment, add /* and then go down one line under the closing brace of the else statement (}) and add */ to close the long comment. The code will now look like this:

```
// Open preview modal and update content
/*
if (this.previewModal) {
    this.previewModal.open();
    this.updateCartContent(this.previewModal, response.data.cart_item.hash);
} else {
    this.$overlay.show();
    // if no modal, redirect to the cart page
    this.redirectTo(response.data.cart_item.cart_url || this.context.urls.cart);
}
*/
this.redirectTo(response.data.cart_item.cart_url || this.context.urls.cart);
```

Let me know if this helps!

Answer (score 2):

Just FYI I went through a similar problem and found that the "Ask a Design partner" forum gave me my answer. The answer I used was from this post:

https://support.bigcommerce.com/s/group/0F913000000HLpWCAW/ask-a-design-partner

But to help I will pull out what they said:

"If you want to remove the popup, you will need to edit the theme files, navigate to the templates/components/products/product-view.html file, and comment out (or remove )this code at the bottom of the file:

```html
<div id="previewModal" class="modal modal--large" data-reveal>
    <a href="#" class="modal-close" aria-label="{{lang 'common.close'}}" role="button">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&#215;</span>
    </a>
    <div class="modal-content"></div>
    <div class="loadingOverlay"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi  You need to do this :

**1.** Login to admin-end then go to store setting

**2.** From top tabs choose display tab

**3.** Find the 'Add to Cart' Action choose what you want pop window or redirection to the cart page.

**4.** hit the save button.

Check image:

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer Raj, but it seems that my project has a new or different version back end. I no longer have that option in the Display tab.